# Generate additional timeseries rows and calculate the average for each items

Tags: python, pyspark, time-series, azure-databricks

I am new to window functions in pyspark and struggling to get the solution.I have following dataset. What I would like to to get average of the previous values and paste to next three months .I am able to get the additional rows of month using the sequence method but I am not sure how to incorporate the above.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
userId  pages   month_date             
1208437  806    2023-05-31T00:00:00.000+0000    
1208437 949 2023-06-30T00:00:00.000+0000    
1208437 949 2023-07-31T00:00:00.000+0000    
1361343 119 2023-05-31T00:00:00.000+0000    
1361343 119 2023-06-30T00:00:00.000+0000    
1361343 64  2023-07-31T00:00:00.000+0000    



My expected output will be:
userId  pages   month_date             
1208437  806    2023-05-31T00:00:00.000+0000    
1208437  949    2023-06-30T00:00:00.000+0000    
1208437  962    2023-07-31T00:00:00.000+0000
1208437  905.6  2023-08-30T00:00:00.000+0000
1208437  905.6  2023-09-31T00:00:00.000+0000
1208437  905.6  2023-10-30T00:00:00.000+0000
1361343 121 2023-05-31T00:00:00.000+0000    
1361343 119 2023-06-30T00:00:00.000+0000    
1361343 64  2023-07-31T00:00:00.000+0000
1361343 101.3   2023-08-30T00:00:00.000+0000    
1361343 101.3   2023-09-31T00:00:00.000+0000    
1361343 101.3   2023-10-30T00:00:00.000+0000
```

To create the dataframes

```
    from datetime import datetime
    from pyspark.sql import types as T
    from pyspark.sql import functions as F

    data = [("1208437","2023-05-31T00:00:00.000+0000",806),
            ("1208437","2023-06-30T00:00:00.000+0000",949),
            ("1208437","2023-07-31T00:00:00.000+0000",962),
            ("1361343","2023-05-31T00:00:00.000+0000",121),
            ("1361343","2023-06-30T00:00:00.000+0000",119),
            ("1361343","2023-07-31T00:00:00.000+0000",64)]

    schema = T.StructType([T.StructField("userId",T.StringType(),True),
                           T.StructField("date",T.StringType(),True), 
                           T.StructField("pages",T.StringType(),True)])
                           
    sdf_prints = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=schema) 
    sdf_prints=sdf_prints.withColumn("timestamp", F.to_timestamp(sdf_prints.date))
```

I have tried to add months and sequence method to generate the additional rows as timestamps but not able to extrapolate the averaged values